# Plotting on Netlogo

Tags: plot, global-variables, netlogo

I've a problem with displaying the plot of a global variable on Netlogo. 
The global variable is called rumour-index and it's implementented as follow:

```
globals
[
   rumour-index
 ]

;; turtle procedure to update the value of the index every time
   to recalculate-index
     let alfa1  count turtles with [ color = black ]
     let alfa2 count turtles with [color = red ]
     set rumour-index alfa1 + 2 * alfa2 
   end
```

Whilst, in the interface I create a plot with a pen which should plot rumour-index but nothing appears on the plot. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `plot rumour-index` as the update commands of one of your plot pens, it should work. If it doesn't, may you're just not calling [`tick`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#tick) or [`update-plots`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#update-plots) at the end of your `go` procedure?

Comment: I tried to write the code from the start and now it works! :/

Comment: Do you know if there's a method which can tell me whether a turtle is connected with another with specified properties?

Comment: It's not a forum :-) each question needs a new slot ! Anyway you can create links during setup procedure. And after that ask connected turtles.